# How to code for iterating through multiple files in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have code which I am trying to update from another example. The aim is to run plink using files of: each chromosome, snp ids, and a file containing only 1 ID which is an individual's ID. Running these files in plink ultimately makes a vcf file per individual for a given chromosome.

I have 22 chromosome files, 1 snp file (which is always the same), and 500 individual files. For each individual I am aiming to make a vcf for each chromosome, so I have 22*500 (11000) vcf files as output.

With doing this at the moment I have tried a bash script with this:

```
ID=$SGE_TASK_ID
indiv=$SGE_TASK_ID

plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual${indiv}.txt
```

This runs, however it only runs through 1 individual, giving me 22 chromosome vcf files for that one person, and stops there. How do I make this run for all 500 people, would it be with a for loop? Looking through other questions I haven't been able to find one that matches my question and is in linux, any help would appreciated.

${indiv} would just be a number, so the text file that runs looks like individual1.txt and increases through the 500 individuals (individual1.txt, individual2.txt, individual3.txt)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `${indiv}` contains no spaces,

```
for indiv in $(<individuals.data); do
    plink [...] individual${indiv}.txt
done
```

The file `individuals.data` would name the individuals, separated by spaces or newlines.

If unsure what the Bash shell's `$(<...)` operator does, try this:

```
for A in $(<individuals.data); do
    echo "[$A]"
done
```

Note that, as @Kaz has observed, if wish your script to work also in shells other than Bash, then you might write `$(cat ...)` rather than `$(<...)`

Comment: There's no need to make that assumption (nor would it be the only assumption you need to make to use `for`). See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @chepner Interesting. I have been using `for` for such purposes without incident since 2004 or so, probably hundreds of times; but I am certainly prepared to be taught a better way of operating. I *think* however that you are mistaken about the spaces.

Comment: More accurately `$(< ...)` is the GNU Bourne-Again Shell's operator. The portable equivalent is `$(cat ...)`. The Bash documentation claims that `$(< ...)` is a faster equivalent for `$(cat ...)`.  This is completely silly; Bash should just take the `$(cat ...)` syntax and translate it to `$(< ...)`, rather than make the programmer do it in the source. Since `cat` is a standard utility, a shell implementation can treat it as built-in. Once Bash is patched to do this, the `$(< ...)` syntax will be a historic dongle.

Comment: @Kaz The answer now integrates observations of yours.

Comment: @tbh If a string from the file contains meta characters like `*` or `?`, the words are subject to pattern matching since the command substitution isn't quoted.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and answers. For the for loop with A, will this know I am looking for it to take the name of a file in another location? Ultimately the ${indiv} is just a number 1-500 if that helps

Comment: Try the command `seq 500`. Do you see what that does? Now what if you replace the `$(< ...)` by `$(seq 500)`? [Notice that the last lacks a `<` because it is not reading from a file.]

Comment: Also, if you prefer 001, 002, 003 ..., rather than 1, 2, 3, ..., you can issue the command `seq -f%03g 500`. That guarantees three digits.