# How to increase numbers in a string with each line in a text file in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have code I want to run 500 times in a bash script (although currently I have been stuck on making a for loop in bash for what I want, so I am thinking I can automate making a larger bash script via python). However, I want one part of to change with each of the 500 iterations - I have a file 'individual1' that needs to increase with each line (so individual1, individual2, individual3 etc.)

Currently in python I have simply done:

```
x  = 'plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual1.txt'

text = ((x+'\n')*500)    

f = open("bash.txt", "r")
out = open("outfile.bg", "w")
for line in f:
    out.write("DBPH" + 1)
out.close()
print(text)
f.close()
```

Although I know this for loop isn't right at all, from trying to learn from similar questions on here I'm still not sure the next steps to take to get it as I want.

The output in the text file would look like:

```
plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual1.txt

plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual2.txt
```

so I'm getting individual1, individual2 etc. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In bash, what you want is `for x in seq 1 500; do plink [..] individual$x.txt; done`

Comment: @BaileyParker you missed the backtick, or more likely SO swallowed them...  you need "for x in \`seq 1 500\`; ...".   How do you put literal backticks inside a backticked expection in SO anyway?

Comment: Thank you for this. It hasn't seemed to work, may be because with this I am just trying to solve one piece of a problem which I've also asked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186485/how-to-code-for-iterating-through-multiple-files-in-linux

Comment: @joanis I did. You can escape them with a backslash, I believe. `for x in \`seq 1 500\`; do plink [..] individual$x.txt; done`

Comment: @BaileyParker Sure enough, it worked. It didn't seem to work in the answer box, but it worked in the comment box. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little script to output that file in the directory that you run the script in.

```
x  = 'plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt --recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam '

times_written = 1

out = open("outfile.bg", "w")
while times_written - 1 < 500:
    out.write(F"{x}individual{times_written}.txt\n")
    times_written += 1
out.close()
```

This block will produce output like:

```
plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual1.txt
plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual2.txt
```

This code here will do the same thing but with a space in the middle:

```
x  = 'plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract 
snps.txt --recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam '

times_written = 1

out = open("outfile.bg", "w")
while times_written - 1 < 500:
    out.write(F"{x}individual{times_written}.txt\n\n")
    times_written += 1
out.close()
```

This will produce output like:

```
plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual1.txt

plink --bed chr${ID}.bed --bim chr${ID}.bim --fam chr${ID}.fam --extract snps.txt
--recode vcf-iid --out output${indiv}chr${ID}vcf --keep-fam individual2.txt
```

Happy coding. Also here is a link with some useful information on Python File I/O https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm.

Comment: This worked thank you! Thank also for the link too!